# Simple test to measure cache lines size

Tags: c++, linux, performance, cpu-cache

Starting from this article - [Gallery of Processor Cache Effects](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/) by Igor Ostrovsky - I wanted to play with his examples on my own machine.
This is my code for the first example, that looks at how touching different cache lines affect running time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int step = 1;

    const int length = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
    int* arr = new int[length];

    timespec t0, t1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t0);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += step) 
        arr[i] *= 3;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);

    long int duration = (t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec);
    if (duration < 0)
        duration = 1000000000 + duration;

    cout<< step << ", " << duration / 1000 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Using various values for step, I don't see the jump in the running time:

```
step, microseconds
1, 451725
2, 334981
3, 287679
4, 261813
5, 254265
6, 246077
16, 215035
32, 207410
64, 202526
128, 197089
256, 195154
```

I would expect to see something similar with:

> But from 16 onwards, the running time is halved each time we double the step.

I test it on an Ubuntu13, Xeon X5450 and compiling it with: g++ -O0.
Is something flawed with my code, or the results are actually ok?
Any insight on what I'm missing would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Measuring performance with `-O0` is a waste of time. Don't do it. Try `-O2` or even `-march=native`, esp. if playing with cachelines.

Comment: @erenon - the -O0 is needed so the array assignment is not optimized away.  The result is not used, so the computation can be deleted.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson: that's not a reason to measure performance without optimization. Use the result then -- it's simple.

Comment: Try disabling HW prefetches, skipping over lines is likely to fool your stream-based ones, so you're not saving the BW as you intended to.

Comment: @erenon - I'm not actually trying to measure performance. Just wanted to "see with my eyes" the effects of cachelines.

Comment: @Leeor - thanks for the hint, will try it and see if that's the reason for not getting expected results.

Comment: @AlinMotogna: If you'd like to "see the cachelines", take a look at `false sharing`.

Answer (score 1):

As i see you want to observe effect of cache line sizes, i recommend tool cachegrind, part of valgrind tool set. Your approach is right but not close to results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int step = atoi(argv[1]);

    const int length = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
    int* arr = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += step) 
        arr[i] *= 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Run tool **valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./a.out $cacheline-size** and you should see results. After plotting this you will get desired results with accuracy. Happy Experimenting!!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CacheLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CacheLine cacheLine = new CacheLine();
    cacheLine.startTesting();
}

private void startTesting() {
    byte[] array = new byte[128 * 1024];
    for (int testIndex = 0; testIndex < 10; testIndex++) {
        testMethod(array);
        System.out.println("--------- // ---------");
    }

}

private void testMethod(byte[] array) {
    for (int len = 8192; len <= array.length; len += 8192) {

        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < len; k += 64) {
                array[k] = 1;
            }
        }

        long dT = System.nanoTime() - t0;
        System.out.println("len: " + len / 1024 + " dT: " + dT + " dT/stepCount: " + (dT) / len);
    }
}
}
```

This code helps you with determining L1 data cache size. You can read about it more in detail here. https://medium.com/@behzodbekqodirov/threading-in-java-194b7db6c1de#.kzt4w8eul